# Back-up table in PostgreSQL. Syntax error

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have SQL commands that compress table to a json file. But when I tried the file name to be dynamic. I'm having an error. ERROR:  syntax error at or near "||"
LINE 12: ...O 'C:\Users\Desktop\database\backup_' || (SELECT...
^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 478

```
-- Calculate the date range for the backup
    SELECT
      (date_trunc('day', now() - interval '30 days'))::timestamp as start_date,
      (date_trunc('day', now()))::timestamp - interval '1 second' as end_date
    INTO TEMPORARY TABLE backup_dates;
    -- Export the backup for the date range
    COPY (
      SELECT *
      FROM mqtt_table
      WHERE created_at < (SELECT start_date FROM backup_dates) OR created_at >= (SELECT end_date FROM backup_dates)
    ) TO 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\database\\backup_' || (SELECT start_date FROM backup_dates)::text || '.json' WITH (FORMAT binary);
    -- Delete backup records
    DELETE FROM mqtt_table
    WHERE created_at < (SELECT start_date FROM backup_dates) OR created_at >= (SELECT end_date FROM backup_dates);
```

Comment: Can you use concat() function instead of pipe `||` and check whether you still get issue.
The line on which error is thrown can be replaced with 


`TO concat('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\database\\backup_', (SELECT start_date FROM backup_dates)::text, '.json') WITH (FORMAT binary);`

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CONCAT"

Comment: I don't think you can specify a dynamic output file name with COPY. You will need to use dynamic SQL (using PL/pgSQL).

Answer (score 0):

The PostgreSQL documentation describes:

```
COPY ...
TO { 'filename' | PROGRAM 'command' | STDOUT }
```

So the file name has to be a string literal, and you cannot use an expression for it. Use dynamic SQL, for example in a `DO` statement.